# Can Solr index/search static files?

Tags: search, solr, indexing

I've been reading [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-solr1/) but I was just wondering, does Solr have the capability to search static files (i.e. outside of a content management system or a database)?

Some of my files are just straight up html...or server side code with html "blocks"...

Comment: You mean uploading rich text documents like PDFs, HTML, docs? THis http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler

Comment: Yes, some are PDFs...but also I have some .cfm files with blocks of HTML inside of them...

Comment: Indexing ColdFusion markup? You got a bit of explaining to do, sir! Solr will index "he is a self-centered jackass" and "he=self::center(++jackass)" **exactly** the same way: extract words from the punctuation (tokenization), remove stop words, then find the root of each word (stemming) and make it available for querying.   Do you want a project like Nullege? Or managing a code repo? TortoiseHG, a mercurial GUI is helpful for that.

Comment: Haha I am not a sir and and I did not build this page...just inherited it. Don't need a code repo, just some way to index content that's in a page with a few includes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SolR can index any text input. The important bit is that it indexes *text*. So if your static files are not text files, you may need to run them through a tool like [Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) first. Then SolR should have no problem indexing the extracted textual data.

Answer (score 0):

There is the ExternalFileField field type. But it's use looks limited.

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/schema/ExternalFileField.html